# What will happen to variable Declared in Interface ? if the implemented class has the same variable?

Tags: java

The code is below.

```
public interface DesignPatternInterface 
{
  int CUSTOMERAGE = 45;

}

public class ImplementInterface extends AbstaractDemo implements DesignPatternInterface 
{
   private static final int  CUSTOMERAGE =20;
}
```

My question is interface variable is static final and memory will be assigned

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: You just asked an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code:

```
interface DesignPatternInterface {
  int CUSTOMERAGE = 45;
}

public class ImplementInterface implements DesignPatternInterface {
   static final int CUSTOMERAGE = 20;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(CUSTOMERAGE);
     System.out.println(DesignPatternInterface.CUSTOMERAGE);
   }
}
```

It will print

```
20
45
```

I believe this should serve as a good practical explanation of your doubt.

Also note that no memory is allocated on the heap for primitive static final variables; the value resides inside the memory structure describing the *class*, not an *instance* of the class. Depending on the details of a specific JVM, the class-describing structure is either in a special heap region reserved for JVM internals, or not on the heap at all.

Comment: +1 You should also add that static members are never inherited, they are shadowed and belong to the class/interface.

Comment: I have edited; actually the member *is* inherited and can be accessed with a simple name. Of course, it doesn't *override* the original, which is still there in the supertype; only the name resolution rules change.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is interface variable is static final

Yes. From [section 9.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Next:

> and memory will be assigned

Not sure what you mean by this. It's just a static final field.

There is no relationship between `DesignPatternInterface.CUSTOMERAGE` and `ImplementInterface.CUSTOMERAGE`. They're entirely separate variables.

Comment: `and memory will be assigned` - IMHO, since the variable is final, the compiler could decide to inline the value, so no (heap) memory would be allocated

Comment: @Andreas: The field still has to exist to some extent, in that it's available for reflection.

Comment: Good point :) So at least *some* memory needs to be allocated for it

Answer (score 1):

Fields in interfaces are always by default `public static`.  This means they belong to class, not instance.

When you access a static field you have to explicitly specify which class you are accessing, so there is no way to override, or even shadow, a static field.

So both values take space in memory and both are always available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Interface and extendable classes. Interfaces are merely a contract that a class implementing them will have (and implement) those methods. If you want to have a field value, you should have it in a class.

```
public class SomeClass {
    protected int someValue = 45;
}

//...
public class OtherClass extends SomeClass {

    public OtherClass() {
        this.someValue = 40;
        //super.someValue == 45
        //this.someValue == 40
    }

}
```